# Debugging Rust in VSCode, no debug symbols on library, but debug symbols on example

Tags: debugging, rust, lldb

I'm trying to debug with LLDB on VSCode. I added a breakpoint into my library, it stops on the breakpoint but I get a call stack with unnamed symbols and I can't see any variables:

[image]

This is an example from the library, which I built with `cargo build --example my_example_name`. I researched and to build in release mode, `--release` should be added. So I think I built in debug mode.

I'd guess the library is being built somehow in release mode. How can I check this?

**If I put the breakpoint in the example file itself, then the symbol appear when the breakpoint happens.
When I put the breakpoint in the library used by the example, then no symbols appear when the breakpoint happens.**

Is it possible that `cargo build --example my_example` builds the example in debug mode but the library in release mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html, "Dependencies use the `dev`/`release` profiles."

To override that, you could try `RUSTFLAGS=-g cargo build ...` (`-g` is equivalent to `-C debuginfo=2`).